# Can't delete file with foreign letters

Tags: bash, language, unicode, rename

I have a file:

```
På hjul.mkv
```

When trying to move or delete file I get

```
rm: can't remove 'På Hjul.mkv': No such file or directory
```

The same thing happens when trying to issue `$ rm *P*` or the like:

```
wobba:/media/disk/ # rm P*
rm: can't remove 'På Hjul.mkv': No such file or directory
```

What can I do to get it removed or renamed?

**EDIT:** The operating system I am using is the Debian based [Openelec Media Center](http://openelec.tv/). The hardddrive is formatted with NTFS and a system restart does not help.

`ls -l P*` acts the same as `rm P*` when it comes to the name:

```
wobba:/media/disk/ # ls -l P*
-rw-------    1 root     root     1395882911 Apr 25 11:17 På Hjul.mkv
```

**EDIT2:** Openelec uses BusyBox, which does not incorporate `-inum` to find `inode number` in its `find` command.

Comment: This looks weird. Any more information? Which OS, which file system, which character set (iso8859-1, utf-8) do you use? What's the output of "ls -l \*P\*"?

Comment: That sounds like a corrupt file, does a system restart help?

Comment: Is this a Windows file system (disk) mounted on a *nix system (or vice-versa)?  See if you can access it with the OS that created it.

Comment: I've editet the question. @Uwe How do I find which charset I am using? I think I am using UTF-8 though

Comment: What's the output of "echo $LC_CTYPE"? Does it contain ".UTF-8"?

Comment: That variable seems to be empty

Comment: Is `rm` an alias?  If this happens again, try `/bin/rm P*`.

Comment: @Scott, I don't understand what you meant by that. What happens again?

Comment: Well, what I meant was:  What happens if you type `alias | grep rm` or `alias rm`?  You (or whoever created your account and/or administers your system) might have defined `rm` to be an alias for `rm -i`, to make `rm` ask for confirmation.  If this is done incorrectly, it can turn `rm "foo bar"` into `rm -i foo bar`; i.e., the problem might actually be with the embedded space and not the foreign letter.  What happens if you `cp /dev/null "foo bar"` and then `rm "foo bar"` or `rm foo*`? …… But, taking another look at your question (after a night’s sleep), I believe that this isn’t your problem.

Comment: BTW, your observations/edits are inconsistent.  You say “`ls -l P*` acts the same as `rm P*` …”, but they don’t.  `ls -l P*` succeeds, and reports file information; `rm P*` fails, reporting “`No such file or directory`”.

Comment: I know this is old but there is always the possibility that the file system was corrupt. Running `fsck` first may have caught and repaired the issue.

Comment: I posted this to the BusyBox mailing list since both issues in this thread were users using BusyBox; just to make them aware of it. I accidentally started a rather long (and on-going) discussion, if anybody is interested: http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2014-May/thread.html#80958

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting it by file id which is normally inode number on ext based filesystems, but for NTFS I'm hoping it'll expose the NFTS file id equivalent which is what you can attempt to use to delete it.

There are no guarantees this will work, but worth trying.  Something like:

```
matt@mattdev::/tmp/ls -il
total 0   
20090 -rw------- 1 matt matt  0 Apr 26 18:27 tmpQJyK5Q
16284 -rw-rw-r-- 1 matt matt  0 Apr 26 18:26 unity_support_test.0
```

followed by:

```
find . -inum 20090 -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Of course, the above is not using NTFS but ext4.  I'm curious to know if it works or not.

Comment: Damnit, Openelec use BusyBox v1.21.0, and it doesn't have the `-inum` parameter in `find` :\ Otherwise, good idea!

Answer (score 1):

Btw, I just had this issue on BusyBox and this solved it for me:

```
$ rm -i *   # CAUTION Be **SURE** you include the '-i' on this command! CAUTION
```

Then, I just answered no to all the files in that directory until I got to the problematic one (in my case, an unprintable char showing up as a question mark, as in: ?filename and then I answered yes).  Poof.  You can ctrl-c the interative rm once you've reached the problematic file.

Comment: I posted this to the BusyBox mailing list since both issues in this thread were users using BusyBox; just to make them aware of it. I accidentally started a rather long (and on-going) discussion, if anybody is interested: http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2014-May/thread.html#80958

Answer (score 0):

To actually get this done I had to use Samba share and delete the file from a Windows computer in the same network. Even so, renaming or moving did not work over Samba either, only removal.

Thanks Scott.

Comment: In other words, you used my suggestion.

Comment: "See if you can access it with the OS that created it", Windows did not create it, but yes, it's quite close to what you mentioned.

Comment: I join the others who feel that this is a weird problem.  Did you originally create the `På hjul.mkv` file on your OpenELEC (Linux) system?  Can you do it again?  If you do, do you have the same problem again, that you can `ls` the file but not `rm` it?  Because it would be really weird for a system to be able to create a file that it cannot delete.